# How to fetch and display the POST Request Body Content in Rest Assured with Junit - Serenity Report

Tags: rest-assured, serenity-bdd, rest-assured-jsonpath, cucumber-serenity

I am using Serenity BDD framework with Rest assured Junit5.
While creating the post request using using 'mvn clean install' command in index file report , I am unable to see the request body. its displaying the path which I provided for the json file. but not the actual POST request body content.

Can someone please advise on how to display the POST Request Body Content in the index file Report.
[image]

Comment: please, add more context, do you use RA with cucumber or screenplay or just Junit5? How does your report look like (add screenshot)? What command to run the test?

Comment: Sure, I have edited the actual post and posted again

Comment: It seems a bug of rest-assured when it log. It will call `toString` of the File --> return path_to_file, instead of file's content.

Comment: @lucas-nguyen-17   Can you please suggest an alternative here so that I can display the Request Body content into the Report.  is there any way out ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Step 1: Convert json file to String.

```
String payload = new String(Files.readAllBytes(Paths.get("path_to_file")));
```

Step 2: Put it in request body

```
given().contentType(ContentType.JSON).body(payload)...
```